# casting to a data.frame in order to sort columns fails with unimplemented type list

Tags: r

Why does the final cast to a data.frame appear not to work? When I try to sort it I get: `Error in order(temp[, 1], decreasing = T) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'`

```
data<-lapply(1:5,function(i){
  lapply(1:5,function(j){
    list(i=i,j=j)
  })
})

temp<-as.data.frame(data)
temp<-matrix(temp,ncol=2,byrow=T)
head(temp,20)
temp<-data.frame(temp)
class(temp) #####IS A DATA.FRAME
temp<-temp[order(temp[,1],decreasing=T),]
```

Comment: That was what I needed. Please post this as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns in the OP's dataset are each `list` of `length` 25.  We can convert it to a normal data.frame with column `vector`s.

```
temp1 <- data.frame(lapply(temp, unlist))
```

and then do the `order`

```
temp1[order(temp1[,1], decreasing = TRUE),]
```

---

It is easier to check the structure of the dataset with `str`

```
str(temp, list.len = 3)
#'data.frame':   25 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ X1:List of 25
#  ..$ : int 1
#  ..$ : int 1
#  ..$ : int 1
#  .. [list output truncated]
# $ X2:List of 25
#  ..$ : int 1
#  ..$ : int 2
#  ..$ : int 3
#  .. [list output truncated]
```

---

Also, we can directly get a `data.frame` with `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(rep(list(1:5), 2))
```

Or using `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(1:5, 1:5)
```